# How to deallocate objects in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, object, nsstring, nsmutablearray, release

i have this Mutable Array:

```
NSMutableArray *points = [pgroute getPoints:self];
```

where `[getPoint...]` do this:

```
{
 NSMutableArray *normPoints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 [normPoints addObject:@""];
 [...]
 return normPoints;
}
```

now,
points is an array of objects, right?
is correct to release *points array in this way?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [points count]; i++) {
    [(NSString *)[points objectAtIndex:i] release];
}
[points release];
```

or it is another correct way?
Xcode compiler, with `RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER` tell me there is an

> Incorrect decrement of the reference
>   count of an object that is not owned
>   at this point by the caller

How can i resolve this?

thanks,
alberto.

Comment: If you want to memory-manage that `NSMutableArray` yourself, you should consider renaming your method such that it contains the word `new`. This is to adhere to Apple's naming conventions that any methods with `alloc`, `init`, `new` or `copy` return objects that must be manually released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to empty the array, just do this:

```
[points removeAllObjects];
```

If you want to release the array, you can even skip that and release it right away:

```
[points release];
```

The array will handle releasing the objects on its own. Then again if you're only adding `NSString` literals (`@"using this notation"`) to the array, they don't need to be released since they are constants. That's a different story of course; my point is that `NSMutableArray` will deal with releasing stuff where necessary for you.

Comment: removeAllObjects, remove also all object reference? It release the n objects in?

Comment: @pask: Yes, the moment you remove an object from the array, it releases its pointer to that object.